Characteristic polynomial of an orthogonal projection
Q: What is the characteristic polynomial of an orthogonal projection onto a (two-dimensional) plane through the origin in $\mathbb R^4$?
Ans: $x^2(x-1)^2$
Can someone please explain how to do this question? I am not sure how to even begin since I am unsure how the characteristic polynomial for an orthogonal projection is even defined. This is the definition of an orthogonal projection that I have been given, but don't know if it can be applied here:
Definition. Let $V$ be an inner product space, $X\leq V$, and $v=x+x^\bot$ where $x\in X$ and $x^\bot\in X^\bot$, the orthogonal complement to $X$. The orthogonal projection from $V$ onto $X$ is $\pi_X:V\to X$ s.t. $\pi_X(v)=x$.

Can you write down an example of an orthogonal projection, as a matrix, and compute its characteristic polynomial? What's the easiest one you can think of?

What are its eigenvectors ?

Let $U$ be two-dimensional plane, $U^{\perp}$ - orthogonal complement of $U$, $P_U$ - projection to $U$. Let $u_1, u_2$ be basis of $U$, $v_1, v_2$ be basis of $U^{\perp}$. $u_1, u_2, v_1, v_2$ form basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$
$P_U(u_1)=u_1$
$P_U(u_2)=u_2$
$P_U(v_1)=0$
$P_U(v_2)=0$
So the matrix of $P_U$ in this basis would be:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
Then,$\chi_{P_U}(t)=$\begin{vmatrix}
t-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & t-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & t & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & t\\
\end{vmatrix} = $(t-1)^2t^2$
